# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.3.0:jar-no-fork

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin

We're getting an error but we're not using maven-source-plugin dependency in pom.xml. Locally build passed successfully while running electric commender job we're facing issue.

`[ERROR] We have duplicated artifacts attached.`
and
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.3.0:jar-no-fork`

[image]

Comment: An text output is much better also the whole output would be much better ...also using maven-war-pugin in version 2.X? Really old .... The log output stated different that you are using maven-source-plugin ...maybe inherited from a parent or alike... without the full pom files it's impossible to help here...BTW: More information like Maven version, JDK etc. is helpful..

Answer (score 0):

I've added the latest Maven source plugin fixed issue

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of *We have duplicated artifacts attached.*  from *source:3.3.0:jar-no-fork (attach-sources)*

The mvn command was run with `clean install deploy`. The issue was fixed after it was modified to `clean deploy`.